# httpd.service failed to start after migraition rhel 8

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I got the error after successful upgraded rhel 8

```
# systemctl start httpd
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

# journalctl -xe
-- The unit man-db-cache-update.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Nov 29 11:42:32 lab-sailpoint systemd[1]: Started man-db-cache-update.service.
-- Subject: Unit man-db-cache-update.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit man-db-cache-update.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 29 11:42:32 lab-sailpoint systemd[1]: run-rbd3d73a7e68848ab8cca4654b83e1581.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- The unit run-rbd3d73a7e68848ab8cca4654b83e1581.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Nov 29 11:48:07 lab-sailpoint systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Nov 29 11:48:07 lab-sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565438 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 lab-sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565519 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 lab-sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565527 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 lab-sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565534 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 lab-sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565541 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 lab-sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565547 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 lab-sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565554 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 lab-sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565561 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 lab-sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565568 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565575 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 sailpoint httpd[25392]: [Wed Nov 29 11:48:07.565582 2023] [so:warn] [pid 25392:tid 13>
Nov 29 11:48:07 sailpoint httpd[25392]: httpd: Syntax error on line 59 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:>
Nov 29 11:48:07 sailpoint systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILU>

# systemctl list-unit-files | egrep 'httpd|sshd|mattermost'
httpd.service                                 disabled
httpd@.service                                **disabled**
sshd-keygen@.service                          disabled
sshd.service                                  enabled
sshd@.service                                 static
httpd.socket                                  disabled
sshd.socket                                   disabled
sshd-keygen.target                            static
```

I worked around and the httpd.service is enabled but still can't start the httpd
now I get more than one MPM Loaded

```
# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-11-29 13:25:25 EST; 7s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 2596 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2596 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 29 13:25:25 sailpoint httpd[2596]: [Wed Nov 29 13:25:25.454837 2023] [so:warn] [pid 2596:tid 1399>
Nov 29 13:25:25 sailpoint httpd[2596]: [Wed Nov 29 13:25:25.454848 2023] [so:warn] [pid 2596:tid 1399>
Nov 29 13:25:25 sailpoint httpd[2596]: [Wed Nov 29 13:25:25.454856 2023] [so:warn] [pid 2596:tid 1399>
Nov 29 13:25:25 sailpoint httpd[2596]: [Wed Nov 29 13:25:25.454867 2023] [so:warn] [pid 2596:tid 1399>
Nov 29 13:25:25 sailpoint httpd[2596]: [Wed Nov 29 13:25:25.454875 2023] [so:warn] [pid 2596:tid 1399>
Nov 29 13:25:25 sailpoint httpd[2596]: [Wed Nov 29 13:25:25.454886 2023] [so:warn] [pid 2596:tid 1399>
Nov 29 13:25:25 sailpoint httpd[2596]: AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: `More than one MPM loaded.`
Nov 29 13:25:25 sailpoint systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILU>
Nov 29 13:25:25 sailpoint systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 29 13:25:25 sailpoint systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

even installed mod_ssl and corrected all the Listen to 80 in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf are not help.  The httpd.conf Listen 80 (already) including allow apache through the firewall for port 80 and 443. I have checked lot os solutions, but these problems still exist.
When I grep 443 on the conf.d file there are existed but not 80

```
# grep  '80' /etc/httpd/conf.d/*
```

Comment: `Nov 29 11:48:07 sailpoint httpd[25392]: httpd: Syntax error on line 59 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:>`

Comment: line 59 of httpd.conf is

" Include conf.modules.d/*.conf "and I don't have this error after the httpd.service enabled.

The error now is "
Nov 29 13:22:20 sailpoint httpd[2572]: AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.
"

Comment: I completed remove httpd, folder and apache user.  Reinstalled apache and enable httpd, all started.